# How to give multiple language support in nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have been given a project made in chinese language that uses nodejs, angularjs, and nodejs also provides restAPIs to mobile apps. I am required to give multiple language support in this project. I have planned to make json files for each language and load the file when required. But i am confused if it is the right way to do the project.

Comment: This is a way to do it. Search on google for `node i18n`, there are some modules to do it

Answer (score 2):

See the modules on npm:

- https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/multilingual
- https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/i18n

There are a lot of them - both specific ones for the framework that you're using and general one to be used in projects independent on the framework.